# CSS class change by class underneath it?

Tags: html, css

Our project usually has a professional web developer that handles this sort of thing.  But ours left, and we're still looking, so this weirdness falls to me.  We have a situation where a list of lines under a node has to affect the parent node's look.

```
<span class="feedback">
  <ul>
    <li class="info">Just an info message</li>
    <li class="error">This is an error</li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

In the above, if all the li's are not error, we want one look, but if there's even ONE error, we want a different look.  Is that something CSS can do?  if so, how?  Is there something I can do on feedback that makes it show one way under no errors, and a different way if there are?

Comment: May I know what will trigger the error? A button? Form?

Comment: You need javascript for this

Comment: Will probably be possible with the CSS4. Atm. the pseudo `:has` can do it but its support is really bad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: No, I don't think it's a dupe of that question because I am asking the exact opposite, if there's a selector going to the child.  I want the feedback class to reflect that there is AT LEAST ONE error class as a child.  That question seems to want the CHILD to discover it's PARENTS.

Comment: Nope, that still sounds like a parent selector, you want to change the appearance of the parent based on a property of a child element. Let's make a hypothetical parent selector `?` you could do what you want with `.error ? .feedback {background-color:#F00;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending class `has-errors` to `span.feedback` on the back-end is not an option? If you have control over what comes from the back-end I'd try to do something like such approach instead (it's somehow simpler):

```
<span class="feedback has-errors">
  <ul>
    <li class="info">Just an info message</li>
    <li class="error">This is an error</li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

Otherwise, as far as I know, it's not possible to accomplish precisely what you're asking only through CSS. But if you use JS, you could also make it happen (far from ideal), IMO.

Comment: @leanroico - Adding a class to the parent is probably possible, just MUCH less elegant.  The server code that generates this section isn't modularized in such a way as to make this easy.  So I figured I'd check if a pure CSS solution was even an option because I knew it could do some stuff, but my CSS isn't strong enough to know if it could do this.

Comment: I see. Yeah, I feel your pain. It's less elegant indeed. I also went through such need already before and never got any satisfactory solution. Maybe on the next CSS spec they can enable us to do so.